# Issue in IE While Combining Background-image and css3- Gradients

Tags: css

I am Combining CSS3 gradient and background image. It is working fine in Chrome and FF and also Background image is getting repeated. in ie9 and Below i am not able to see the Background image. Any one please help me

```
body{background: #d5cea6; /* Old browsers */
background-image:url("cc.png"), -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d5cea6 0%, #c9c190 40%, #b7ad70 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background-image: url("cc.png"),-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#d5cea6), color-stop(40%,#c9c190), color-stop(100%,#b7ad70)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background-image: url("cc.png"),-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d5cea6 0%,#c9c190 40%,#b7ad70 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background-image:url("cc.png"), -o-linear-gradient(top, #d5cea6 0%,#c9c190 40%,#b7ad70 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background-image: url("cc.png"),-ms-linear-gradient(top, #d5cea6 0%,#c9c190 40%,#b7ad70 100%); /* IE10+ */
background-image:url("cc.png"), linear-gradient(to bottom, #d5cea6 0%,#c9c190 40%,#b7ad70 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d5cea6', endColorstr='#b7ad70',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

This is the code i used

Comment: Not sure. The `filter` style should work (unless you have activeX disabled). By the way, off topic, but IE10 doesn't need an `-ms-` style for gradients; it supports it without a prefixe. The prefixed version was only needed for the IE10 preview versions (which *no-one* is using now).

Comment: One question: please confirm that you are actually using real copies of IE9 and below, and not testing using IE10's compat modes? Because that *will* break, as IE10 doesn't support the `filter` styles, even in compat mode. If you're testing, you *must* use real copies of each IE version you want to support.

Comment: i am using ie10 Compact modes @Spudley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no it won't work. You will not be able to do this with IE's old `filter` style if you're trying to combine a background image and a gradient into the same background.

The only way I know of to make this work reliably in old IE versions is to use the [CSS3Pie library](http://css3pie.com/).

Using this library, it is possible to specify standard CSS code in old IE versiosn for various modern features, including gradients.

Download the PIE.htc script, add it into your site, then add the following lines to your CSS (and remove the `filter` line):

```
-pie-background: url("cc.png"), linear-gradient(to bottom, #d5cea6 0%,#c9c190 40%,#b7ad70 100%);  /* PIE */
behavior: url(PIE.htc); /* change the URL as appropriate for your site */
```

Now your background should behave the same even in really old IE versions as it does in modern browsers.

Hope that helps.

See also [the CSS3Pie documentation](http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/#pie-background).

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much for your kind support.